# How to open a web package after deploying in IIS7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, web-deployment

I've deployed my ASP MVC 4 application in IIS 7 as a web package, but I don't know how to open it in a browser. I've followed all  [these](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/import-a-package-through-iis-manager) instructions but I don't know the next step. Any help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy to the *default web site*, as the guide you link to specifies, then you will most likely be able to browse `http://localhost` (on the default port 80) after deployment.

If you import to another site I'm sure the address of that site is visible in IIS manager, if nothing else you should be able to click on `Browse web site` (normally in the right hand pane).

[Some more details regarding web deploy packages](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/deployment/web-deployment-in-the-enterprise/manually-installing-web-packages)